# Could not load IOSurface for time string. Rendering locally instead swift 4

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4.2

Could you help me with this problem when I running my project :

> Could not load IOSurface for time string. Rendering locally instead

I don't know what is going on with my codding ..... pleas help .

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem after upgrading to swift 4.2.

Comment: yes , bro . So I don't know any thing wrong with my code or not ?

Comment: Perhaps providing some code or context would help?

Comment: How many XCode do you have on your machine?

Comment: Anyone is facing the similar issue on iOS development with iPad?

Comment: @nikhilgohil11 only one bro .

Comment: I also had this issue when I was debugging and doing a screen recording at the same time on device. It seemed that the screen recording was causing this.

Comment: @Sojourner9 Any solution of this??????

Comment: Only the one I hate which is to set OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to disable in the scheme.

Comment: Please, give me more detail . :(

Comment: Did Anybody fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem. Select target -> General -> select Devices with Universal and select Main Interface for iPhone & iPad.
[image]

Comment: Could you be more precise? Select target? where? which App? Xcode? Simulator?

Comment: @Krischu Updated my answer.

Comment: In my case: only Devices Universal. But this solution works for me.

Comment: @Markus it doesn't work app crashing when i'm continuously push and pop viewcontroller with ARSCNView around 7 to 8 times then app crashes with above error