# Could not load IOSurface for time string. Rendering locally instead

Tags: xcode, swift4

anyone know how to fix the below problem which shows up when I running my project :

> Could not load IOSurface for time string. Rendering locally instead swift 4

I did not any of update xcode, pod, It all of sudden appeared on the xcode log.

Comment: Duplicate of [ios - Could not load IOSurface for time string, rendering locally instead swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52846886/1107226)